# I'm not happy with the dual boot menu on Windows 8 - how can I improve or replace it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, multi-boot

I have Windows 8 and windows XP on two separate partitions. I don't like Windows 8 default boot menu because:

- It doesn't load right after turning on the computer, but after Windows 8 is already loaded
- Minimal time to wait before loading default OS is 5 seconds.

Can I replace it with custom boot menu, and how?

---

Also, I installed Windows XP after installing Windows 7. Now there is a problem in XP - drive letters are wrong - XP system drive is not C, but E. Can this be fixed too?

Comment: have you looked at something like GRUB ?